# How can I make this one-liner work in DOS?

Tags: python, command-line

```
python -c "for x in range(1,10) print x"
```

I enjoy python one liners with -c, but it is limited when indentation is needed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
python -c "for x in range(1,10): print x"
```

Just add the colon.

To address the question in the comments:

> How can I make this work though? python -c "import calendar;print calendar.prcal(2009);for x in range(1,10): print x"

```
python -c "for x in range(1,10): x==1 and __import__('calendar').prcal(2009); print x;"
```

As you can see it's pretty gross. We can't import before the loop. To get around this we check if x is at the first iteration in the loop, if so we do the import.

More examples [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071223101511/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-April/199822.html).

Comment: @Luis: you need to add the colon anyway, even when not running from a command line.

Comment: How can I make this work though?
python -c "import calendar;print calendar.prcal(2009);for x in range(1,10): print x"

Comment: @Luis: there are limits on one-liners; and you've found the limit.  Good work.

Answer (score 3):

Not a python script, but might help:

```
for /L %i in (1, 1, 10) do echo %i
```

Answer (score 3):

```
python -c "for x in range(1,10): print x"
```

Remember the ":" !!

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want this?

python -c “for x in range(1,10): print x”

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't require putting a statement after the colon, which is not considered very highly.

```
python2 -c "print '\n'.join([str(x) for x in range(1,10)])"
```

What's more pythonic than a list comprehension!

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't actually like this any better.  I put statements after colons more than I should.  Probably because I have a widescreen monitor.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c 'print "\n".join(map(str, range(1,10)))'
```

but what's wrong in a "real" python script? (you know, a foo.py launched via "python foo.py")
If you really like one-liners, I suggest perl :)